# Adding Un-editable text to the end of each line of a contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, text, html, text-editor, contenteditable

I have a contenteditable div, but I want to add a few characters of uneditable, unselectable text to the end of each line.
 I have mocked up an example bellow, which adds a note of whether all the words on the line were spelled correctly or not:

[image]

My div is a pretty simple contenteditable div:

```
<div contentEditable="true" designMode="on" id="edit" style="border: 1px dashed black; width: 700px; height: 400px"></div>
```

Any idea how to tackle this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use `float:right` to position your good/bad labels on the right, and have the content flow around them.  The alignment wouldn't be exactly like your example, but it might be made to work.

It might look something like [this example at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fZabU/).

---

**Update**

Here's a different approach that might work, depending on your needs: [see jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fZabU/1/).

In this second approach, I've split each line into its own `<div>`, and followed each line's div with a `<span contentEditable=false>(Good!)``.  I've floated everything to the left, with a`clear:left` on the divs, so that each div lands on its own line.  This does exactly what you want (at least, in webkit browsers) -- as long as you can split your lines up like that.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly the behavior I was trying to create! :)

Comment: Question: How can I create a new div and (Good!) span each time the user adds a new line or hits enter?

Comment: You'll have to tweak it a good bit to make it nice, but [here's an updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fZabU/3/) that shows the basic idea.

Comment: I tried testing that on my server, but I can't get jQuery to work: http://unlock-guide.com/write/editor.html . Do you happen to know why? Do I need to use .ready()? This is one of my first times using jQuery, so sorry for the slow pace.

Comment: Yes. As it stands, the javascript code is executed before the html document is built.  Because the `#edit` div doesn't yet exist at that time, the DOMNodeInserted event is never bound.  To solve this, you need to wrap the code in `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })` or move your script block to the bottom of the `<body>` element.

Comment: I should also note that [Mutation Events (including DOMNodeInserted) are deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mutationevents) by the DOM Level 3 spec.  But I don't think there is a reasonable way to accomplish your goal without using them.  The note in the spec makes clear that they intend to specify a replacement for Mutation Events at some point in the future.  I suspect that browsers will not remove this functionality until the replacement has been spec'd and implemented.

Answer (score 0):

you should be super imposing a div (z-index greater than content div) on top of the contentEditable div with text "Good!","Error" etc.. This way, the content would not be editable through the contentEditable div.

You should be able to calculate the position of the div based on the number of characters on a line and the line number.